# Как получить координаты draggable метки в Google Maps Android API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

На карте находятся несколько `draggable` меток. Как можно получить новые  координаты метки, после того, как она была передвинута пользователем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто: [OnMarkerDragListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener) в помощь.

---

```
[Ваш маркер].draggable(true);

 googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                    //взять координаты до перемещения
                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                    //взять координаты после перемещения
                    LatLng pos = marker.getPosition();
                    marker.setSnippet(pos.latitude + "," + pos.longitude);
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                    //брать координаты во время перемещения
                }
            });
```